# How to get the address of the device with C

Tags: c, linux

I get the id of my hard disk like this:

```
system("hdparm -i /dev/xxx > /tmp/hdid");
```

How can I get the device name (`/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/hda`, etc) from a program in C?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear at all to me - If this is Linux then try:

getmntent() to enumerate mounted file systems

The /proc/mounts directory lists mounted devices

The /dev/disks directory lists disk devices, their names are usually sda, sdb, etc.  This includes devices that are not mounted.  The entries there are symlinks, so readlink or ls -l will reveal the target.

Comment: Ok... the problem is that I want to know which device (/dev/hda or /dev/sda or /dev/sdb .. etc) will run my program in C, thus to be able to execute hdparm -i /dev/xxx correctly.
I hope you understand me.
regards

Comment: @CarlosCarranza You should be given that in first arg of main() - the full path to your exe, which includes the disk and directory

Comment: Yes together with the "getmntent"- OK.